# Special character encoding (PC8) in Java file writing

Tags: java, character-encoding

I need to write a file with Java in PC8 character encoding. How can a 'custom' character set be applied to a (text) file?

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
    try {     
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
              new FileOutputStream("test.txt"), "utf-8")); // obviously need to change this

        String info = "#TEST \"test åäö\"";
        writer.write(info);

        writer.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
```

So I'd need to know if it is even possible to write in a special character encoding, and what do I need to do? Specifying "PC-8" or "PC8" in the encoding did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer while writing the question itself. Here is the list of supported character encodings for Java, and how to specify them in the code block I provided in the question: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

So this is what works for me:

```
writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
              new FileOutputStream("test.txt"), "ibm-437"));
```

What caused problems in my case was that Google was littered with questions for UTF-8 character encoding. Furthermore, PC8 is not the official name for the character encoding, so I couldn't find the needed information with that name. Hope this helps generally with encoding problems.